# top 5 order sum by means of correlated query

Tags: mysql, sql

create a view that returns customer number, customer name, total order value (i.e., dollar amount. Note only to count the shipped orders) for all customers. Then use the view to retrieve the top 5 customers with the highest total order value. Note that you cannot create the view on the server! In order to test the view you created on the server, you may treat the view as a piece of SQL.

```
the customer ,order and orderdetails,Payments table table structure is as follows

Customer:

customerNumber
customerName
contactLastName
contactFirstName
phoneNo
addresline1
city

Orders:
orderNumber
orderDate
requiredDate
customerNumber
shippedDate
status
comments

orderdetails:

orderNumber
productCode
quantityOrdered
priceEach
orderLineNumber

Payment:
customerNumber
checkNumber
paymentDate
amount
```

I can get the top5 by LIMIT but I am trying to use correlated query and i have written the following query.I  know it is wrong. Can someone help me get the answer by means of co-related query

```
select C.customerNumber,C.customerName,sum(OD.priceeach) T
from customers C,orders O,orderdetails OD
where C.customerNumber=O.customerNumber 
and O.orderNumber=OD.orderNumber
group by C.customerNumber and  5>=( 
select count(*) from 
 customers CS,orders OS,orderdetails OD1
where CS.customerNumber=OS.customerNumber 
and OS.orderNumber=OD1.orderNumber
and T<sum(OD1.priceeach)
group by C.customerNumber)
```

I know we can't pass sum in co-related query.IS there any method to solve it.

Comment: Could you please provide more data as described https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example because i can't see what for you need your count

Comment: Whats wrong with your query?

Comment: Your table is not called order. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: i am getting below error: Error Code: 1247. Reference 'T' not supported (reference to group function) 0.187 sec

Comment: Did you miss the `AS`  keyword?
`sum(OD.priceeach) AS T`

Comment: @Tony adding AS won't help

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use a comparison in a GROUP BY clause. This doesn't make any sense and is likely the source of your confusion.

Any time you use a sub-query, it must be given a name and to properly link to the core query it should be part of a conditional expression (`WHERE ... IN` for example)

Without using a nested (co-related) query, the problem can be solved using this query:

```
select 
    C.customerNumber, C.customerName, sum(priceEach*quantityOrdered) as T 
FROM Customer C
INNER JOIN Orders O on O.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
INNER JOIN orderdetails OD ON OD.orderNumber=O.orderNumber
GROUP BY C.customerNumber
ORDER BY T desc
LIMIT 0,5
```

If a nested (co-related) query is needed, you can use this:

```
SELECT 
    customerNumber, customerName, OT.T 
FROM Customer C,
(
    SELECT O.customerNumber, sum(priceEach * quantityOrdered) as T from Orders
    INNER JOIN orderdetails OD ON OD.orderNumber=O.orderNumber
    GROUP BY O.customerNumber
    ORDER BY T desc
    LIMIT 0,5
) as OT
WHERE OT.customerNumber=C.customerNumber
```

Comment: not really, since you are looking for the top 5 customers by order value from within a grouping of a ll customers with orders.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. You can solve it without using LIMIT. you can use TOP. See here: (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) LIMIT is the MySQL implementation, TOP is MS SQL and Oracle uses ROWNUM - as mentioned at that link